# Capacitor identification help please

Tags: power, capacitor, identification

I have a generator which consists of a Honda GC160 engine and a Stephill brushless generator.

After being left for around 6 months without being run, I started it up and noticed there was no power output.

Upon inspection and removal of the top cover where the extension cord plugs in I noticed this white capacitor which has exploded. The top was slightly ajar and there is solid grey material which has come out.

I’m looking to identify the capacitor so I can order a new one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It’s a shame it has cracked where it has as it would make the job easier in identifying the correct replacement.

[image: photo of capacitor]

After removing the grey material which had come out:

[image: photo of capacitor]

On the top line it has

1.27.6CA3 MKP
13uf +- 5%
?????? 10000h/CLASS B
??????3000h/CLASS C

-25/85/21

On the side it has P3 13AA

Comment: Get a service manual for it.

Comment: Looks like a standard motor start or run capacitor of 13uF. A motor rewinder, hvac or electrical wholesaler should be able to supply.

Comment: Kartman - Thank you… I’m not super knowledgeable when it comes to capacitors and resistors and the like.

Comment: Andy aka… there is no service manual for this model. It’s a company in England that make their own generator setups. They buy Honda engines and fit their own brushless motor. I have the service manual for the engine however… and for the few generators I have seen as an all-in-one from the factory, I’ve still never seen a section on capacitor diagnosis or replacement, so I don’t think your answer is all that helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 13µF +/-5% 470V metalized polypropylene (MKP) motor capacitor made by Arcotronics, rated for operation from -25°C to 85°C.

It probably died from moisture ingress.